# Запись в файл fprintf (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте.

Вот небольшой фрагмент программы, который в общем то и портит всю малину.

**Вариант 1.**

```
 string MainStr; FILE *Storage; 
   Storage=fopen("StorageF.txt", "wt");

    std::cin>>MainStr;

    fprintf(Storage, "%s", MainStr);
    fclose(Storage);

    Storage=fopen("StorageF.txt", "rt");
    fscanf(Storage, "%d", MainStr);

    std::cout<<MainStr<<"\n";
```

Программа отрабатывает, в папке с ней появляется файл StroageF.txt который заполнен, не тем, что я ввел с клавиатуры, а каким то бессмысленным сочетанием русских букв.

**Вариант 2.**

```
string MainStr; FILE *Storage;
Storage=fopen("StorageF.txt", "rt");
fscanf(Storage, "%d", MainStr);

std::cout<<MainStr<<"\n";
```

StorageF.txt уже создан и заполнен цифрами либо латинскими символами, но в консоли ничего не отображается там, где отрабатывает cout - пустая строка.

**Суть:** Не хочу вводить строку руками, хочу, что бы строка заполняляась данными из файла, что я не правильно сделал?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вывести функцией C класс string.
Замените:

```
fprintf(Storage, "%s", MainStr);
```

на

```
fprintf(Storage, "%s", MainStr.c_str());
```

метод c_str() класса string возвращает const char*, как раз то что принимает fprintf.

ADD:

да и зачем вы сочетаете C и C++ в одном коде.
Считываем строку из файла.

```
std::string MainStr;
std::fstream file("Storage.txt");
std::getline(file, MainStr);
file.close();
std::cout << MainStr.c_str();
```

Записываем строку в файл.

```
std::string MainStr = "Test String for file";
std::fstream file("Storage2.txt");
file << MainStr.c_str();
file.close();
```

Comment: Ооо спасибо) Я честно говоря и не знал, что происходит сочетание такого рода, смотрел статьи в инете, по запросу "Строки С++", и нашел fprintf и тому подобное)

Comment: И еще неплохо посоветовать автору вопроса обратить внимание на спецификаторы в `printf`/`scanf`, т.к `%d` в данном случае явно не уместен.

Comment: Это на самом деле моя опечатка, там везде %s

Comment: @BlackOverlord ну так подправте текст вопроса (нажмите *править* внизу вопроса) ...